# How to perform form submission with FormElement

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to submit a form after selecting the option from a dropdown. Below is my form:

### Form code

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post">
    <label class="floatl"> Select </label>
    <select class="form-control floatl" id="BankStatus" onchange="getBankStatus()">
        <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
        <option value="Y-1">Success</option>
        <option value="N-0">Failure</option>
    </select>
    <br clear="all">
    <br clear="all">
    <button type="button" name="formSubmit" id="SubmitForm" onClick="validateform()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <br clear="all">
    <br clear="all">
    <input type="hidden" id="txnres" name="txnres" value="">
</form>
```

I am able to change the option to Success by below code, but I'm not sure how I can submit my form now.

```
Connection.Response resp = Jsoup.connect(url) //
                 .timeout(30000)
                 .method(Connection.Method.GET) //
                 .execute();
//System.out.println(resp.body());
Document responseDocument = resp.parse();
Element potentialForm = responseDocument.select("form#form1").first();
FormElement form = (FormElement) potentialForm;
Element mySelect=form.getElementsByAttributeValue("id", "BankStatus").get(0);
Elements options = mySelect.getElementsByTag("option");
Element Sucessoption=options.get(1);
Element falseoption=options.get(0);
Sucessoption.attr("selected","selected");
falseoption.removeAttr("selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [**FormElement.submit()**](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/FormElement.html#submit()) method. It creates a new **[Connection](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html)** object which you can then execute:

```java
Connection formConnect = form.submit();
Connection.Response formResponse = formConnect.execute();
Document formDoc = formResponse.parse();
```

The `submit` method prepares the submission from the form details including the data, the GET or POST method, etc. You can add other settings to `formConnect` (new cookies, or a file upload data, etc) before executing it.